# What type of tablet does Yuito use?

Tags: irozuku-sekai-no-ashita-kara

In *Irozuku Sekai no Ashita kara*, Yuito uses a tablet to make such a colorful drawing.

[image: front view of the tablet]

[image: another front view of the tablet]

[image: back view of the tablet]

I've searched for many brands of display screen monitors but didn't find any matches.

I thought it was a Wacom monitor, from a Japanese company. But this seems impossible since they only connect to a PC and don't function alone.

What type of tablet did Yuito use?

Comment: Do you maybe have a timestamp from the first episode. And maybe even an image of it?

Comment: [Cintiq Companion 2](https://us-store.wacom.com/Product/cintiq-companion-2#/) can be use as a stand alone tablet powered by Intel processors

Comment: I'll search for it, thanks, don't know how to pin a good answer though